# Realm and React error. Can't resolve 'react-native' in app created with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, realm

I'm attempting to add the Realm package to a project created with create-react-app. I simply run the create script, install the project, then install realm. When I attempt to import or require 'realm' I get a *Can't resolve 'react-native'* error.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm i
npm i --save realm
npm start
```

At this point, if I attempt to import realm anywhere in the project, for instance by adding:

```
import Realm from 'realm';
```

or

```
Realm = require('realm');
```

to App.js or Index.js

I get the following error.

```
./node_modules/realm/lib/browser/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in '/Users/scolobey/Desktop/Projects/realm-blog/node_modules/realm/lib/browser'
```

As far as I have been able to tell, this seems to be related to webpack. Opening the console on this error page, I see:

```
./node_modules/realm/lib/browser/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in '/Users/scolobey/Desktop/Projects/javascript/my-app/node_modules/realm/lib/browser'
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
r @ backend.js:6
handleErrors @ webpackHotDevClient.js:173
push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:212
```

Answer (score 2):

Create React App is for regular React apps (not mobile/“React Native” apps). Your app is complaining because it expects to find the “react-native” package, which doesn’t come included with Create React App.

You’ll note that [Realm](https://npm.im/realm)’s [Installation Guide](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/) specifically instructs you to set up react native before installing the package.

As mentioned in the  [React Native Docs - Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) (which is linked to in the above Realm installation guide), you likely want to use [expo](https://expo.io/learn) instead of Create React App.

Once the React Native app is set up, you can proceed with installing Realm.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still lost, but maybe you can straighten me out. In the [Installation Guide](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/) link, there are 2 tabs. 'React Native', and 'Node.js'. I'm not interested in React Native. [This tutorial](https://academy.realm.io/posts/realm-node-js-express-blog-tutorial/) demonstrates what I'm after, a web-only app (not including 'react-native') and I can get it to work fine. But adding Realm to my React app fails.

Comment: The tutorial shows how to build a node/express app - not sure how react is related to that? Are you just assuming you could get it to work with a generic react app? The docs suggest you can either use node or react-native, no mention of react.

Comment: Basically, yes. I was told that Realm won't run in the browser. But that tutorial kinda made it seem like it's running in the browser. Looks like my solution will need [this](https://docs.realm.io/sync/graphql-web-access). I'm still a little confused as to why it works with Express, but thanks for the help.

Comment: Express is a back-end framework, whereas React is a front-end library. Sounds like you could either build an express back-end with realm that your react front end consumes or, as you mentioned, you can use graphql (likely with Apollo: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/).